# Issues when writing a medium/large system

Tags: java, python, ruby, system, enterprise

There is some hype with languages like Python (that I like very much) and Ruby but I was writing a medium-size system in Python and feel the lack of some tools that I would have if I was using Java: Eclipse features, JUnit integration and some language-features like catching some errors in compile time.

Some people says that Java is dead as a language. But large important software are written in Java: Hadoop, Lucene and many others.

Is Java a better language than Python or Ruby for medium/large infrastructure software like these?

Comment: "better" language?  By better do you mean faster?  More expensive?  Larger run-time memory footprint?  What do you mean by "better"?

Answer (score 1):

You make a valid point in saying that Java is more suited to enterprise software. That's really where Java shines: it works very well for enterprise programming.

However, your gripes about the tools in Python and Ruby are unfounded. PyDev for Eclipse takes full advantage of the same features that you would enjoy if you were developing in Java. Ruby has a similar plugin for Eclipse. Unit testing frameworks like pyunit, nose, and others exist for both languages (and I believe PyDev has support for unit tests). Also, just like a Java compiler would catch an error at compile time, a Python script will give syntax errors before you run it, along with an (IMO) much more understandable error system than a Java compiler.

Since Python and Ruby are scripting languages, their area of expertise lies more in small tasks, rapid development, and using frameworks like Django or Rails. So yes, more heavy-duty languages like Java are great for enterprise, but there's something to be said for the elegance and ease of use of Python and Ruby.

Comment: @S. Lott: I misspoke. I used some of the language that the question's author used, when by "system" he really meant "enterprise". Whatever, it's been corrected

Comment: "Java is more suited to enterprise software"?  Without a definition for "Enterprise"  this answer doesn't seem particularly helpful.  Could you expand in it by defining "Enterprise"?

Comment: Arguable opinion incoming: "Enterprise software" in my world translates to => "less coding, much technology integration", in essence "assembling" the software from ready-made pieces, rather than inventing them. A concept I frankly never seen working in my 7 years of Java experience and being in 10+ organizations throughout my carreer.

Comment: "Java is more suited to enterprise software" only in the sense that in the corporate world nobody will blame you for choosing Java, even when things go badly. With python or ruby you will find yourself questioned about your choice ten times a day for every little glitch (sad but true).

Comment: @Paulo: it's part the politics, but also part the framework that exists

Answer (score 1):

This kind of question can get very argumentative... For enterprise software most of time the key factor is political, not technical.

If you own the business, stick with the technology that best fits your vision. If not, use Java - it is politically safer.

On the technical field, it is almost a tie.

Comment: +1: Since "better" is undefined in the question, it is **subjective**.  Since it claims "lack of some tools" and "Java is dead", it is also **argumentative**.

Answer (score 0):

All much of a muchness really. There are features in Python/Ruby that your aware of that make them a more appealing offering than say Java. Static typing can be your best friend most of the time, and a pain for the other.

Lack of tooling is related to adoption. Java/c# has a larger adoption.

Corporates/Enterprises and medium to large organizations, like to procure solutions with contracts as opposed to technical merits.

From experience Python does have some speed issues, I can't comment on Ruby, but I imagine that if your applications require dedicated speed I would not use python.

Also threading and multi-core processing is not as good as it could be in python, although 2.7 seems to improve a lot of the old problems, I think the GIL problem still remains for threading.

My only comment on Java is that it now has Oracle behind it, and depending where your sitting and how you like Oracle, might change your attitude to Java. especially if your designing for Open Source solutions.

Comment: I would trade human productivity for performance any day of week as nowadays hardware is less expensive than developers.

Comment: @Paulo: couldn't agree more. Being able to attack the problems [almost-]directly (a concept applying very strongly in Ruby and much less so in Java) is to be a productive developer. We are paid to be productive, right? ;)

Comment: All much of a muchness, To a degree all languages are equal, some are easier to do somethings than others. If your skilled in your language then most of the time the results look the same. Its all swings and roundabouts. I do a couple of languages each got their good points and bad. The one that has got me intrigued at the moment is F#. Complete paradigm shift, keeps me on my toes :)